# Querying and updating a deeply nested object with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the below schema

```
const ButtonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    conditions: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
})

// Data Model
const DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    buttons: [ButtonSchema],
    __v: {type: Number, default: 0}
})

//Question Model
const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data: [DataSchema],
    __v: {type: Number, default: 0}
})

// Dialog Model
const Dialog = mongoose.model('Dialog', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    questions: [QuestionSchema]
}))
```

so essentially , the object is like this

```
{
    "download_data": [
        {
            "__v": 0,
            "data": [
                {
                    "text": [
                        "xxxx"
                    ],
                    "__v": 0,
                    "buttons": [],
                    "_id": "5afdf6cf1c1cc542c4580511",
                    "conditions": {
                        "false": {
                            "type": "endDialog",
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "text": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5afdf6cf1c1cc542c4580510",
            "type": "confirm"
        },
        {
            "__v": 0,
            "data": [
                {
                    "text": [
                        "xxxx"
                    ],
                    "__v": 0,
                    "buttons": [],
                    "_id": "5afdf6cf1c1cc542c458050f"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5afdf6cf1c1cc542c458050e",
            "type": "endDialog"
        }
    ]}
```

As you can see , i have unique ids for for the Question Object and ids for Data objects

During an update , i would ideally like to only update a particular Data field by _id

I can retrieve a particular question by this

```
return DialogSchema.findOne({'questions._id': req.params.subId})
    .then(function(data){
         // this doesnt work
        return data.questions[req.params.index].update(req.body)
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log('data :', data)
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('err: ', err)
    })
```

But ideally, i would just like to retrieve the DataSchema Object (inserted as an array objects in the QuestionsSchema object)

but this doesnt work

```
  return DialogSchema.findOne({'questions.data._id': req.params.subId})
        .then(function(data){
            console.log('data : ', data)
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('err: ', err)
        })
```

Is there a way i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Because your `data` field into the `QuestionSchema` is an array, you can't merely access nested properties for a sub-document. Your first query to retrieve the Question and then the Data must be updated a little bit. First of all, it's not the Schema but your Model instance which queries for the data. And because `req.params.subId` is a `Question` Id, it will be more efficient to make a query on that model:

```
return Question.findOne({'_id': req.params.subId})
.then(function(question) {
    ...
})
```

But in order to update a specific question's data, you need to update the Question model, not the Data model:

```
...
.then(function(question) {
   questions.data[req.params.index] = req.body
   return question.save()
}
```

You need to do that because sub-documents are saved with their parent document. Check the mongoose doc, [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

Note that `questions.data` should return an Array of `ObjectId`, not an Array of `Data` documents. To solve that, you can use the `populate()` method, like the following:

```
return Question.findOne({'_id': req.params.subId})
.populate('data')
.then(function(question) {
    // Here questions.data is an Array of sub-documents
    ...
})
```

If necessary, you can filter or sort the populated `data` array (Mongoose doc, [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate)).

Just a small comment about the `VersionKey (__v)` within your schemas. This property is set by Mongoose by default. Thus you could remove them. Check the Mongoose documentation about [it](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey).